# dbix might_have and prefetch it's relationships on first access?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Example

I have a table that might_have an expansion board; an expansion board has_many locks

Is it possible to when the might_have is first accessed to prefetch the locks?

(Yes I know that when I get the table I can prefetch the board and it's locks; just wondering if I have to do it this way.)

```
package Table;

__PACKAGE__->might_have("expansion_board", "ExpansionBoard",
{ "foreign.boardid" => "self.boardid" });

#etc.

package ExpansionBoard;

__PACKAGE__->has_many("locks","Lock",
{ "foreign.boardid" => "self.boardid" },
undef);

#etc.

package Lock;

#etc.
```

I would most like that $table->expansion_board on first access to also load in it's locks from the database.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please [edit] and clarify what you're trying to do. Please use proper inline-code markup for the things that are methods or config values. It's very hard to read your question.

Comment: @simbabque updated; you can also look at nwellnhof's answer.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you have something like

```
my $board = $result->expansion_board;
```

and want to prefetch the board's locks. In this case, you could use the [`search_related` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base#search_related) with a [`prefetch` attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#prefetch):

```
my $board = $result->search_related('expansion_board', undef, {
    prefetch => 'locks',
})->single;
```

Or you could try the [`find_related` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base#find_related):

```
my $board = $result->find_related('expansion_board', undef, {
    prefetch => 'locks',
});
```

Comment: Does your prefetch cache the board and locks relationships, so that $result->expansion_board and $result->expansion_board->locks will not need the DB again?

Is there a way to have this setup so that on the first occurrence of
my $board = $result->expansion_board; would at the same time as loading in the expansion_board to also get the locks.  (i.e. old code is using $result->expansion_board )

Comment: @melutovich (1) The only thing I know for sure is that `$board->locks` shouldn't hit the DB. I don't think other accesses through the original `$result` are cached. Try to run DBIC with SQL tracing and have a look at the statements it generates. (2) Maybe you could try to override the `expansion_board` method in the result class, but I wouldn't recommend that.